# Remote car controlling

Tags: control, wheel

Before I start asking you for help let you know that I am newbie in electronic field.

All I want to know is the principle of wheel rotation (left-right) from remote car gadget. I am not talking about changing the spin rotation of DC motor (up,down buttons from remote), I am asking about left and right movement of wheel.

I know that spin change depends on polarity of DC motor, so changing polarity changes spin, but what is the principle of changing the left and right positions of front wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DC motor has 2 directions, `forwards` and `backwards`.

The DC motor **does not** control the direction of an RC car, instead it's the **steering mechanism**.

Rather than write everything here - I have found [an article](http://rc4beginners.blogspot.co.nz/p/lesson-4-steering-system_06.html) for you that I believe will explain the principles of car steering. Hopefully it's a good starting point for you; feel free to Google for further information that you require.

The term [`how car steering works`](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=2&gs_ri=hp&tok=BBu9JIbGhlO8CVJL8oOmfQ&cp=22&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=how+car+steering+works&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=how+car+steering+works&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.dGI&fp=6daf5ba8052c93de&biw=1527&bih=840) returns **a lot** of results. Good luck!